# Solving an equation using Matlab

Tags: math, matlab

```
S=solve(strcat('a*gamma(1+(1/b))=',int2str(m)),strcat('a*a*gamma(1+(2/b))=',int2str(c)));
```

Values of variables m and c are known. How can one solve for a and b?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a and b are arbitrary constants. You can assign it as syms. If you really need to solve for a and b, use two equations two unknowns or the solve() function in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the optimization toolkit if you have it:

```
f = @(a,b)  (a(1)*gamma(1+(1/a(2))) - b(1))^2 +  (a(1)^2*gamma(1+(2/a(2)))-b(2))^2;
X = fminsearch(@(a) f(a,b),[1;1])
```